# Unused battery life in electronic device?

Tags: batteries

Why do batteries in an unused device die out in time? Is it because, even if the circuit is open, - terminal is in touch/connected with a metal inside the device? Or, is it due to chemicals, since sometimes they melt, but only in devices.

Comment: Batteries have self-leakage resistance just like capacitors yet the best Alkaline might have a shelf life stamped by the year and the poorest do not. Chemical purity comes at a cost.

Comment: There are batteries designed for long life that are unactivated until needed, once activated then they have a designed lifespan.

Comment: Different battery chemistries have different "self-discharge" characteristics. A NiMH rechargeable might lose as much as 30% of its charge per month, whereas a lithium-thionyl-chloride primary cell might last 25 years. There is no perfect battery, although they do get (slightly) better every year.

Comment: Two of the above three comments should be made into answers.  They're spot on.  Batteries just self-discharge.  Some faster, some slower, but they all do.

Comment: I don't know if I'll mix these together into an answer myself, but if someone else gets to it first, perhaps mention that in addition to self discharge, some devices do not completely turn off, allowing a trickle current through electronics even in the off state.